# execute php file on load

Tags: php, ajax, html

I have a PHP file create_json.php that creates a json file from a table in my database i want my app to load that file in order to recreate the json file every time i start it

here is what i tried to do

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function(){  

           $.ajax({

                type: "GET",

                url: "create_json.php" ,

                success : function() { 

                   alert("created");

                }

            }).error(function(){

            alert('error... ohh no!');

          });

        }

</script>
```

I have no error i get the "created alert but the file is not created and i'm sure that my create_json.php file works it works perfectly when i execute it on a browser it just dont work on my app help please here is the php file content

```
$conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to     mysql"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,"bd") or die ("no database");   

$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user"); 

$response = array();
$user = array();
$result=$sql;

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$email=$row['email']; 
$mdp=$row['mdp']; 

$user[] = array('email'=> $email, 'mdp'=> $mdp);

} 

$response['user'] = $user;

$fp = fopen('C:\Users\Oussemat\Documents\PFE11\www\results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($response));
fclose($fp);



?>
```

Comment: first way to debug is to use the `network` tab of browsers, you'll know whats up

Comment: what is the content of `create_json.php` as it's hard to guess with this configuration..

Comment: there you go i added the php script

Answer (score 1):

Try the following script.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

           $.ajax({

                type: "GET",

                url: "create_json.php" ,

                success : function() { 

                   alert("created");

                }

            }).error(function(){

            alert('error... ohh no!');

          });

        });  

</script>
```